# Selenium: How to deal with web elements that get hidden when you try to inspect them? Python 3.x related

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, dom, xpath

I'm about to finish developing an automated program on Python and the only thing that's stopping me it's a web element that gets immediately hidden when I try to inspect it from an **OpenSea** page (can't share the link here since it requires to be connected to my wallet):

[image: problem]

So far, I have only managed to get the `XPATH` and the `CSS_SELECTOR` of this problematic element (`div#tippy-298`) which is the following:

```
button_problematic_xpath = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tippy-298"]')
button_problematic_css = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#tippy-298')
```

But what I need is to get the `XPATH` or `CSS_SELECTOR` of the Web Elements that `button_problematic_css` contains, more specifically the **"Starting"** and **"Ending"** `Textboxes` :

[image: desired elements]

Also, just in case, the element that's on top of `button_problematic_css` is called "Duration", here's its `XPATH`:

```
button_duration = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="duration"]').click #after clicked it deploys div#tippy-298 element
```

**I was wondering if there could be any method to force the visibility** of this `button_problematic_css` using the `Chrome Console` in the Inspection of Web Elements, or **by using an specific method** from `Selenium` on `Python3.x` **to inmediately download all of the web elements this page has right after** `button_problematic_css` is visible.

What I have tried so far is to manually inspect the element, by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + C and` and then clicking the elements contained in `button_problematic_css` which just ends up hiding this element before even clicking its content, the same happens when trying to display the contents of this element in the DOM of this page, it just dissapears.

I just wish my program could be capable of editing the dates in the **"Starting"** and **"Ending"** `Textboxes`

Comment: driver.page_source  printing that might work after you click the element.

Comment: Sure, it works, although it prints a lot of unorganized web elements, is there a way I can filter it somehow? to reduce the data just to the elements I need? @ArundeepChohan

Comment: Not sure but I'd just look for labels or inputs. ctrl f <label or <input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of working, I managed to solve this, it happened that in order to get the XPATH from these particular elements, I had to use the `Chrome Console` and type `$('#duration').click();`.

In this case, `#duration` is a Selector that can be used to get the web element button that allows you to edit the period of time you want to set when clicked.

I guess the general statement would be something like this:

`$('#your_css_selector').click();`

[image: solved]

Now, this way I could managed to look deeper in the DOM without making them hide again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to click the button to show the element. why did I guess? you need to show the url

or u can also try this code:

```
clickmore=WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 'blabalabla')))
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", clickmore) 
button_duration = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="duration"]').click()
```